# Form is submitting when validation error is coming also how to resolve this?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Hi I wrote validation method for save button,error message is coming but form is submitting,How to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use `<apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="return checkRepCust();" action="{!doSave}"  oncomplete="executeWS();" rendered="{!NOT(isEditOperation)}" /> 
                `

Comment: Hi i tried to kept return in onclick now the form is not submitting if error is not coming also

Comment: check if without error you are getting true?

Comment: Can you post your VF and APex code? Posting code will help us debug.